# How to LEFT JOIN three tables with the same column name

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a three tables that are left join. two of them have uid as user id. Problem is every time query execute it takes the same user id.

Please check the table structure

```
-------------------------------------
|Users      |posts      |favorites  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|user_id    |id         |id         |
|username   |title      |uid        |
|password   |post       |post_id    |
|           |uid        |           |
|           |favorites  |           |
-------------------------------------
```

MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM favorites 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = favorites.uid 
LEFT JOIN posts ON favorites.posts_id = posts.id
WHERE favorites.uid='$id' and posts.active=1
```

please note that $id is the profile owner (user) id. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `favorites.photo_id` is a typo, right?

Comment: @juergend sorry it was a typo only here. i edited here.

Comment: And what do you mean by *every time query execute it takes the same user id*?

Comment: Give the table columns clearer names, I have a problem finding which ones are the foreign keys and what all the ids do. Also you need to describe what you want to get before saying how you have tried to get it. Is favorites in the post table the foreign key for favorites in that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table was as follows (I've renamed `user_id`, `post`, and `favorites` columns to clarify their roles as I understand them)

```
-------------------------------------
|Users      |posts      |favorites  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|id         |id         |id         |
|username   |title      |uid        |
|password   |post_text  |post_id    |
|           |uid        |           |
|           |fav_id     |           |
-------------------------------------
```

This sql code can be used to get what (I think) you want

```
SELECT * FROM favorites 
LEFT JOIN posts ON  favorites.id = posts.fav_id
LEFT JOIN users ON posts.uid = users.id
WHERE favorites.uid='$id' and posts.active=1
```

This should get all the details of favorite posts from the three tables for the given user id. Hope it works for you.

Comment: at last thanks it work just had to do few typo fixing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you please try this once

```
SELECT posts.*, favorites.post_id, users.username FROM favorites LEFT JOIN users ON favorites.uid = users.user_id LEFT JOIN posts ON favorites.post_id = posts.id
WHERE users.user_id='$id' and posts.active=1
```

As there was a typo in the query and i have made few changes to your code

Comment: @maxlk i have made some more changes can you please try now

Answer (score 0):

This query may solve your problem.

```
SELECT * FROM post p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN favorites f ON u.user_id = f.id) as tbl1
WHERE p.id=tbl1.post_id and p.uid = $uid and p.active=1
```