# Mysql query not grouping in order

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure if this information is sufficient. 
I have few tables and i am running this query which is returning me the below results.

```
SELECT   CONCAT(pm.fname, " " ,pm.lname) AS fullname,cl.id as clubid,pm.id as player_id,

    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.82) ) * cos( radians( cm.lat ) )
     * cos( radians( -0.373 ) - radians(-0.373) ) + sin( radians(50.82) )
     * sin( radians( cm.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance

FROM clubmapper AS cm

LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs AS cl ON cl.id = cm.club_id

INNER JOIN playermaster AS pm ON pm.id = cm.usertype_id

LEFT JOIN countries AS co ON co.country_code = pm.nationality

WHERE (pm.fname LIKE 'josephthirtye%' OR pm.lname LIKE 'josephthirtye%')   

#group by cm.usertype_id

ORDER BY distance  ASC,pm.fname ASC, pm.lname ASC
LIMIT 0,12
```

This query returns me the below table:

[image]

But i want only the first result whre distance is min. I tried to use group by (commented in the query) but thats giving me the last row. I want only the first row of that player_id

And advice ?

**Below is the same query with pretty print:**

[image]

Some more data:
[image]

**I want unique player_id's whose distance is least**

Comment: change your limit to 1?

Comment: `order by distance ASC limit 1`

Comment: i cant do that..there are other users as well..

Comment: can you provide some data so we can understand what the issue is?

Comment: I have showed the query and results in a way so that its easy to understand. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: yes but thats with only one user.. it would be helpful for us to have some data to work with so we can replicate a query. it would be best if you could provide a sqlfiddle.com for your question

Comment: The scenario is highly complex. Basically there are some players in playermaster table. There are some clubs in club table. Players are link with multiple clubs in another table called clubmapper which also contains the lat/long of those clubs. The application takes the lat/long of the viewing user and displays the players closest to them.

Comment: Sure..I will provide more data.

Comment: I have added more data in my question. Thanks

Comment: group by and order by the *same* fields not different fields

Comment: It wont accept group by distance as its not a column in any table. Distance is a calculated column.

Comment: @developerwjk that is bad advice as mysql can group by any columns... read the documentation..  dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause."

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Do you want one single row with the least distance or do you want the least distance by every player with a name that conforms with your WHERE clause?

Comment: I want the least distance by every player with a name that conforms with  WHERE clause

Comment: Why don't you use a `GROUP BY` clause to only display unique distances?

Comment: Try using only left join and chaining foreign keys from one table to the next like this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864319/how-to-left-join-three-tables-with-the-same-column-name/24865939#24865939](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864319/how-to-left-join-three-tables-with-the-same-column-name/24865939#24865939). For a more specific answer please provide a sketch of your table's relationships and their foreign/primary keys

Comment: @silkfire, ditance is a calculated column. So i cannot use group by clause on that

Comment: @inkalimeva, i have tried all those..It didnt work

Comment: @AbhishekSaha If you add `MIN()` around your distance column and `GROUP BY pm.id`, what happens then?

Comment: Yes thats what i tried initially. but in that case its giving me the record having max distance. Basically with min and without min is giving the same result.

Comment: Try wrapping your query in an outer query so that you properly can select and group from that inner table you show us.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Check my answer below, I think your joining is fine and the problem lies in the filtering of the result

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i solved it. Thanks everybody for suggestions.

```
SELECT   CONCAT(pm.fname, " " ,pm.lname) AS fullname,cl.id as clubid,pm.id as player_id    

FROM (SELECT ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.82) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )
     * cos( radians( -0.373 ) - radians(-0.373) ) + sin( radians(50.82) )
     * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM clubmapper) AS cm

LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs AS cl ON cl.id = cm.club_id

INNER JOIN playermaster AS pm ON pm.id = cm.usertype_id

LEFT JOIN countries AS co ON co.country_code = pm.nationality

WHERE (pm.fname LIKE 'josephthirtye%' OR pm.lname LIKE 'josephthirtye%')   

group by pm.id

ORDER BY distance  ASC,pm.fname ASC, pm.lname ASC

LIMIT 0,12
```

Comment: So I can see you were inspired by the solution I posted in my comment ;)

Comment: this is not a solution. if you notice the comment i posted on your answer.. the group by can and will select other items besides the ordered result.

Answer (score 0):

> But i want only the first result whre distance is min

This query will give you the result with the least distance

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(pm.fname, ' ', pm.lname) AS fullname,
    cl.id as clubid,
    pm.id as player_id,
    MIN(3959 * acos(cos(radians(50.82)) * cos(radians(cm.lat)) * cos(radians(- 0.373) - radians(- 0.373)) + sin(radians(50.82)) * sin(radians(cm.lat)))) AS Distance
FROM
    clubmapper AS cm
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    clubs AS cl ON cl.id = cm.club_id
        INNER JOIN
    playermaster AS pm ON pm.id = cm.usertype_id
        LEFT JOIN
    countries AS co ON co.country_code = pm.nationality
WHERE
    (pm.fname LIKE 'josephthirtye%'
        OR pm.lname LIKE 'josephthirtye%');
```

I don't know if this is what you wanted but part of your problem seemed getting just one result.